# How to center UIImageView in ScrollView (Zooming)

Tags: objective-c, uiscrollview, uiimageview, zooming

I'm trying to zooming UIImageView in `UIScrollView`. And i've got this:

```
-(UIView *)viewForZoomingInScrollView:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
return imageView;
}

-(void)scrollViewDidZoom:(UIScrollView *)scrollView {
[imageView setCenter:CGPointMake(scrollView.center.x, scrollView.center.y)];
}

-(void)scrollViewDidEndZooming:(UIScrollView *)scrollView withView:(UIView *)view atScale:(float)scale {
}
```

Problem is: When i'm zooming out image it's centered, but when i'm zooming in, image is shifted to left up corner.

Where is problem with my code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer is remove all from `scrollViewDidZoom:` and add:

```
[self centerScrollViewContent];
```

Method implementation:

```
- (void)centerScrollViewContents {
CGSize boundsSize = self.scrollView.bounds.size;
CGRect contentsFrame = self.containerView.frame;

if (contentsFrame.size.width < boundsSize.width) {
    contentsFrame.origin.x = (boundsSize.width - contentsFrame.size.width) / 2.0f;
} else {
    contentsFrame.origin.x = 0.0f;
}

if (contentsFrame.size.height < boundsSize.height) {
    contentsFrame.origin.y = (boundsSize.height - contentsFrame.size.height) / 2.0f;
} else {
    contentsFrame.origin.y = 0.0f;
}

self.containerView.frame = contentsFrame;
}
```